# Detect double tap on the empty space of the home screen

Tags: android

I want to detect the double tap on the home screen of android. I saw the  sendWallpaperCommand on Wallpaper manager [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html). Any suggestion will be highly helpful.

Comment: Implement your own home screen.

Comment: How I can implement my own home screen with double tap receiver? Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `android write home screen app` turns up many hits on a search engine, such as [this one](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-custom-launcher-on-android--cms-21358). You can detect double-tap gestures in your own activity, such as your own home screen, via a `GestureDetector`.

Comment: Hello, will designing custom screen will replace default home screen. As what I have noticed that different devices have different default home screens.

Comment: "will designing custom screen will replace default home screen" -- the user can choose whether to use your home screen, their device default home screen, or any other home screen that the user chooses to install.

Comment: Can we implement double tap without replacing the default home screen because some wallpaper apps have already achieved the double tap on default home screen?

Comment: "because some wallpaper apps have already achieved the double tap on default home screen?" -- they are being forwarded events by the home screen. You are welcome to implement a live wallpaper if you want. However, bear in mind that not every home screen supports live wallpaper, and not every home screen will forward events to live wallpaper. Beyond that, you have no way to know what "the empty space of the home screen" is unless you are the one implementing the home screen.